# JNA not working on AIX platform

Tags: java, java-native-interface, aix, jna

JNA is working just fine on the Windows side of things. However, when I port it over to AIX and attempt to run my Java program, I get a "Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: jnidispatch (/com/sun/jna/aix-ppc/libjnidis
patch.a) not found in resource path" error.

I opened up the jna.jar file to look at the resources, and indeed there is no aix-ppc directory in /com/sun/jna/.

Does anyone know how to add in the resources for the AIX platform or where I can find the necessary documentation for this? The jar is already referenced by the project, and I have Eclipse packaging all the necessary libraries into the runnable jar file.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using IBM's JVM?   We use JNA under AIX and don't have any issues.

Comment: Yes, here is what I have. `$ java -version
java version "1.6.0"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build pap3260sr8-20100409_01(SR8))
IBM J9 VM (build 2.4, JRE 1.6.0 IBM J9 2.4 AIX ppc-32 jvmap3260sr8-20100401_55940 (JIT enabled, AOT enabled)
J9VM - 20100401_055940
JIT  - r9_20100401_15339
GC   - 20100308_AA)
JCL  - 20100408_018`

Comment: Did you have to compile JNA specifically on the AIX side or did you just grab the JNA.jar and package it with the project jar? All my development is done on the Windows side of things and then I copy the JAR over to the AIX environment to run and test.

Comment: @shiara, no need to recompile jna.jar.  The rest of the java code we do build/compile under AIX, as well as the JNI side/libraries (of course).

Answer (score 2):

I have just ported JNA for AIX-PPC and AIX-PPC64
It has been submitted to JNA author (twal) for review and approval.
Meanwhile, login http://github.com/SitChenNam/jna
and downlaod the /dist/jna.jar.

keep me informed if it works for you

Answer (score 0):

I assume you can take the source and have to compile it for yourself. Hopefully AIX is not much different from Linux in these aspects.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not so easy. Can't find anybody who succeeded